# Persisting a JavaScript setTimeout function call across postbacks as user browses application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

I believe I can use utilize the following functions to create delayed JavaScript alerts:

```
setTimeout(), clearTimeout(), setInterval() and clearInterval()
```

But how can I use them accross postbacks. For example:

A user has a list of reminders stored in the database. When user logs into site I can access those reminders and call something like:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert("Reminder 1"); }, 10000);
```

Depending on when the reminder due date/time is.

However as the user switches pages before the alert notification happens I believe the setTimeout call won't persist.

Is the only way to get this to work to look up the users reminders on every single postback and do a setTimeout on every page or in some sort of master page?

Comment: `I believe the setTimeout call won't persist` - correct, if it's a postback, not a partial postback

Comment: Client script is "reloaded"/"reset" on page (re)load, unless you have some SPA/XHR/Ajax navigation that handles changes of views - which _doesn't_ (re)load a page and all it's resources (html, css, script). You'll also have to clarify what you mean by "postback" - since that's a key term in ASP.Net Webforms, though you did tag your question with `asp.net-core` which negates WebForms context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really the way to do this. If your trying to build some sort of notification system then ideally it should be driven server side.

In a normal multi-page site every time you render a page the server would check for notifications and then in your template render an alert or some UI feature that tells the user they have notifications.

That set-up won't be active, IE if a new notification is posted on the server the client page won't know about it. Unless you use a notification message api for example pubnub.

Something like [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com) would let you send the message to your page, and in your JS code get a callback, so you can render it in your dom.

Since you have a multi-page app you would need to fetch / request for the notifications on every page render. Running a timeout to trigger for an ahead of time moment is not an ideal solution.

Another way to do it is to poll your server from your js code say every 5 mins and ask for notifications.

That has a price tag on all those repeated calls to your server. The best bet is to use something like [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com) but that comes at an extra laden of code server side to make it work.

Comment: is pubnub basically the same as signalr and hangfire?

Comment: Yes it is. Ideally what you should do is a have a table/class on your server in your db for notifications in the table have the id that represents the user in your app. Each time you add a notification row use your db's trigger/event system to send that row data out to a channel that has the user id + "_notification". On your client web page listen on the users channel. Then when the client gets a message render it in your dom.